# How to programmatically change the other applications Permission by my application on a new version of Androids?

Tags: java, android, events

I have a question regarding the application permissions. How can I change other application permissions by my own application?

Is it achievable to change the Permission for a specific app?
(Without Root)

Comment: I hope not....if another application can do this, your device will not be secure anymore. The only one who can change permission settings should be the user....

Comment: Imagine what a **security flaw** would it be, if it was possible!